setTimeout doesnt work with combineLatest
I have a dynamic form which i m using multiple observables to load data. When all observables emit value, i want to set my form to pristine state. Only problem is that one of my observables is inside of a setTimeout and i cant change that part of code. Is there any alternative way to achieve to set my form to pristine state ? like any way to make combineLatest to wait the observable which is inside of setTimeout ?
Here when all observables emit value i m setting the form in pristine state.
combineLatest(this.exceptionTypes$, this.currencyList$, this.priorityList$, this.dataTypeList$, this.escalationLevelList$, this.synchronisationList$)
      .subscribe(val => {this.caseOverviewForm.markAsPristine()})

Here is the problem that my last observable inside of the setTimeout and i cant change this. this is effecting combine latest to fire.
private _loadSynchronistionList(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.synchronisationList$ = of(SYNCHRONISATION_LIST).pipe(mapAndPatch(this.caseOverviewForm, FormFields.synchronisation, this.detail.id!));
    });
  }


Instead of initializing synchronisationList$ inside of setTimeout, it would be better to make it a Subject (or ReplaySubject(1)) and push the value inside setTimeout by calling synchronisationList$.next().

maybe use timer from rxjs
